# Nginx redirect for old urls

Tags: nginx

My old blog is at

example.com /blog/post_perma_link

I would like the hits to the /blog/* pages to be forwarded to another site

http://otherexample.com/something/something/post_perma_link

The server that will still be hosting the original example.com domain is nginx, therefore what can I do to make sure this forward happens only on /blog/* hits?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your server {} block

```
rewrite ^/blog/(.*) http://otherexample.com/something/something/$1 permanent;
```